# My application is crashing when i press the button inside a tabbed activity for every alternate run

Tags: java, android, listview, crash

My application is crashing when I press the button inside a tabbed activity for the second time.

It works fine the first time,but crashes on every alternative trial. This activity has two `Edittext`, one add button, a `listview` and a `longclicklistener` for each `listview` item.

```
public class Tab3pmedicines extends Fragment {
    private EditText medname,meddosage;
    private Button add,delete;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseauth;
    private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    ListView ListViewMedicine;
    List<MedicineProfile> medicine;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3pmedicines, container, false);
          medname = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.medicinenameID);
          meddosage = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.dosageID);
          add  = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.addmedbtnID);
          ListViewMedicine = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listViewID);
          medicine = new ArrayList<>();

        FirebaseUser currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        String RegisteredUserID = currentUser.getUid();
        databaseReference =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(RegisteredUserID).child("Medicines");

        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addmedicines();
            }
        });

     ListViewMedicine.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
          @Override
          public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
              MedicineProfile medicines = medicine.get(position);
              String medicineID = medicines.getMedid();
              showPopup(medicineID);
              return false;
          }
      });
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                medicine.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot medicinesnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    MedicineProfile medicineP = medicinesnapshot.getValue(MedicineProfile.class);
                    medicine.add(medicineP);
                }

                MedicineList adapter = new MedicineList(Tab3pmedicines.this.getActivity(),medicine);
                ListViewMedicine.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void showPopup(String medid){
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Tab3pmedicines.this.getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_popup,null);
        dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
        final String id = medid;
        final TextView message = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.deleteviewID);
       delete = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.delbtnID);

        final AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

       delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                deleteMedicine(id);
                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }

        });

    }
       private void deleteMedicine(String id1){
        FirebaseUser currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        String RegisteredUserID = currentUser.getUid();
        DatabaseReference dmedicine = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(RegisteredUserID).child("Medicines").child(id1);
        dmedicine.removeValue();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Medicine deleted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void addmedicines(){
        String mname = medname.getText().toString().trim();
        String dosage = meddosage.getText().toString().trim();
        String id = databaseReference.push().getKey();

        if(validate()){
            MedicineProfile medicineProfile = new MedicineProfile(id,mname,dosage);
           databaseReference.child(id).setValue(medicineProfile);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Medicine added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private boolean validate(){
        Boolean result = false;
       String mediname = medname.getText().toString();
        String medidos = meddosage.getText().toString();

        if (mediname.isEmpty() || medidos.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Enter the medicine details",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

LOGCAT :-

```
enter code here

04-07 12:57:45.292 23551-23551/? E/Zygote: v2
04-07 12:57:45.292 23551-23551/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
04-07 12:58:16.062 23551-23551/com.example.mylaptop.myapplicationnps E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
04-07 12:58:17.562 23551-23551/com.example.mylaptop.myapplicationnps E/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = null
04-07 12:58:17.562 23551-23551/com.example.mylaptop.myapplicationnps E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@dd1127d
04-07 12:58:22.642 23551-23551/com.example.mylaptop.myapplicationnps E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
04-07 12:58:51.202 23551-23551/com.example.mylaptop.myapplicationnps E/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = null
04-07 12:58:51.202 23551-23551/com.example.mylaptop.myapplicationnps E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@30bc1e5
04-07 12:58:56.702 23551-23551/com.example.mylaptop.myapplicationnps E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                       Process: com.example.mylaptop.myapplicationnps, PID: 23551
                                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.from(LayoutInflater.java:234)
                                                                                           at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:178)
                                                                                           at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:163)
                                                                                           at com.example.mylaptop.myapplicationnps.MedicineList.<init>(MedicineList.java:0)
                                                                                           at com.example.mylaptop.myapplicationnps.Tab3pmedicines$4.onDataChange(Tab3pmedicines.java:142)
                                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzegf.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeia.zzbyc(Unknown Source)
                                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeig.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

This is the logcat error we get when the app crashes after switching the tabs.

Comment: paste your Logcat or Show which error show you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: Mohammad Ali I have added my logcat error :)

Answer (score 0):

try moving the button initialization to onCreate()

```
delete = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.delbtnID);
```

this line of code